# instagram блокировка устройства

Tags: facebook, instagram, blocks

После примерно 2 регистрации аккаунтов с одного устройства(pc, браузер) в инстограмм, дальнейшие регистрации запрещаются. Скажите как делается блокировка и как ее снять. Не встречал подобное.
ip адресс динамический, пробовал регистрироваться с private window в браузере,чистить куки и менять браузер. Не помогло.

**UP**  Вариант зайти с pc через TOR так же не решает вопрос

Comment: а пробовали через Tor?

Comment: Пробовал через Tor, так же не получается. Но когда беру какой нибудь другой телефон, подключаю его к wifi то регистрация проходит, и опять же только два раза. Потом и это устройство не регает.

Comment: а пробовали после блокировки создать новое соединение в Tor?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman только что попробовал, все введено верно но пишет все так же *Sorry, something went wrong creating your account. Please try again soon.*